# Visual Studio 2012: MVC, Umbraco site extremely slow while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco, azure-sql-database, umbraco7

Windows 8.1 Pro, Visual Studio 2012 Update 4, MVC4 Umbraco site using SQL Azure (have also tried with a local SQL 2008 R2 db). Running through IIS.

Site runs perfectly while not debugging. However, when debugging the site is extremely slow. The default page takes nearly a minute and a half to execute. Subsequent requests take the same amount of time.

I thought this may be environmental (Surface Pro 3, i5), so went over to a MacBook Pro (i7)...issue still occurs on that PC as well.

At my wits end trying to figure out what could be causing it.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

There are several thing that could be happening here. Using an Azure SQL db would cause slower initial loading of pages (compared to a local db) because of the data transfer time. However, subsequent page loads should be quick because everything would be loaded into the site cache.

If subsequent page loads are still extremely slow then this could be because the XML cache isn't being generated. Check that the settings are correct in the web.config in debug configuration.

Also, check where you are writing your debug logging to. Umbraco will write log messages to a log file in `App_Data/Logs/` and also separate logs to the database. Using a remote database would make these writes slower.

Without knowing what else is happening in your project it's difficult to know what other factors may be playing a part. But you need to step through the application in debug mode in VS and you can check the event viewer for swallowed errors like timeouts. Finally, you can use a profiler to pin point exactly where your issue is.